# Async unit test fail to return a value

Tags: .net, unit-testing, task, moq, xunit

I am coding a unit test for an UWP application using Moq and xUnit.  I coded a custom HttpClient mock and the response message with this :

```
public sealed class HttpClientMock : IHttpClient
{
    private string _response;

    public HttpClientMock(string response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    public bool SimulateBasStatusCode { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    { }

    public async Task<IHttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string request)
    {
        IHttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessageMock(_response);

        return await Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}

public sealed class HttpResponseMessageMock : IHttpResponseMessage
{
    private string _response;

    public HttpResponseMessageMock(string response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    public bool SimulateBadSuccessStatusCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsSuccessStatusCode
    {
        get
        {
            return !SimulateBadSuccessStatusCode;
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(_response);
    }
}
```

The unit under test is this :

```
internal async Task<T> GetAndSerialize<T>(string request)
{
    T res = default(T);

    using (_httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
        IHttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string xml = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

            res = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

In this last class, _httpClient is pushed to the unit under test class constructor and in this case, it is my HttpClientMock class.

When I launch my test, I can see GetAndSerialize being called.  It then call HttpClientMock and return correctly an instance of HttpResponseMessageMock but the debugger begin to be extremely slow and complain about a System.Threadind.Tasks.Task.SetNotificationForWaitCompletion having timed out.

I continue and I can see ReadAsStringAsync of my HttpResponseMessageMock being called and return into the unit under test.  It continue correctly, deserialize ok and return without problem.

But once it comes back into my test method, I can see the returned object is not null as the debugger show its type, but if I try to drill down, it take about 5 seconds and show only "?".  No properties are shown.

Later in the test, I make an assert for a property of the returned object and it is seen as null.

I tried and searched for three hours without success.  Do you have any suggestions?

Here is an abbreviated version of the test class :

```
public class TestClass
{
    private const string OBJECT_MOCK = "<ObjectMock testResponse='Test Value'/>";

    [Fact]
    public async Task FailTest()
    {
        /////
        // Arrange

        IHttpClient httpClient = new HttpClientMock(OBJECT_MOCK);
        TestedService mySvc = new TestesService(httpClient);

        /////
        // Act

        ObjectMock response = await mySvc.GetAndSerialize<ObjectMock>("/TestRelativeURL");

        /////
        // Assert

        Assert.NotNull(response);
        Assert.Equal("Test Value", response.TestResponse);
    }
}
```

And here is the ObjectMock class :

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("ObjectMock")]
public sealed class ObjectMock
{
    [XmlElement("testResponse")]
    public string TestResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake, I discovered it when I added the ObjectMock class in the post.  The serialized version I push is `"<ObjectMock testResponse='Test Value'/>"`, but the testResponse attribute is annoted XmlElement in the ObjectMock class.

When I corrected it to XmlAttribute, there is no delay anymore, no SetNotificationForWaitCompletion timeout and the property value is asserted correctly in my test method.

I suppose the XmlElement/XmlAttribute inversion caused an exception who produced the delays in the tasks and caused the timeout.

Another [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) win !

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us. I'm glad you've figured out the problem. :) When you get a minute, please mark this as the accepted answer.